# Google Maps geocoding API issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I'm doing a challenge of local weather display, I wanna get the city and the country from the lan and lat data, so I used google maps geocode api, but I can't access to the name of the city and the country fields.

Here's the piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&key=[KEY HERE]',
    success: function(response) {
        $disply.append('<p><strong>city:</strong>' + response.results[0].address_components[5].long_name +
            '<strong>country:</strong>' + response.results[0].address_components[6].long_name + '</p>')
    }
})
```

The browser displays this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'address_components' of undefined

Although I can make sure that my request succeeded by making an alert, maybe it will be relevant to state that I'm making that Ajax inside another one (for getting lat and lng data.)

to make it more clear, here's the whole of code

```
$('document').ready(function() {
var UR1='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?';
var key='API_KEY';
var lon; 
var lat;
var path;
var $disply=$('#tempDisply');


$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
  var str=response.loc;
  str=str.slice(',')
  lon=str[1];
  lat=str[0];
 path=UR1+'lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon+key+'&units=metric';



    $.ajax({

            url:path,
            success: function(data){
                $disply.append('<h2>temp= '+data.main.temp + '<h2>')}});

                $.ajax({
                url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng'+lat+','+lon+'&key=API_KEY&sensor=true',
            success: function(response){

                $disply.append('<p><strong>city:</strong>'+response.results[0].address_components[5].long_name +'<br>'+
                '<strong>country:</strong>'+response.results[0].address_components[6].long_name+'</p>')}})
    }, "jsonp")

    })
```

Comment: do a console.log(response) to see the data.

Comment: can you how all your code looks like you didn't define the `address_components`

Comment: Vinod Louis : result: Object {results: Array[0], status: "ZERO_RESULTS"}!! request returned seems to be empty !!

Comment: Teocci: I edited my question, u can see the whole of code